# VTK for 3D sonography array data visualization

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, visualization, vtk

I am trying to display 3D sonography(array data) using VTK. I using VTK volume to plot it, but it look strange.
3D sonography array size is 27*460*750

[3D sonography visualize in VTK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c7xE.png)

I have tried using pyvista, and it works, but the needed is using VTK.
[3D sonography visualize in pyvista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpxCm.png)

Thanks in advance.

This is my code :

```
    # import array data (3D sonography array data)
    AArray = sonography

    # dataImporter
    dataImporter = vtk.vtkImageImport()
    data_string = AArray.tobytes()
    dataImporter.CopyImportVoidPointer(data_string, len(data_string))
    dataImporter.SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar() 
    dataImporter.SetNumberOfScalarComponents(1)
    z, x, y = AArray.shape[:3] 
    dataImporter.SetDataExtent(0, z - 1, 0, x - 1, 0, y - 1)
    dataImporter.SetWholeExtent(0, z - 1, 0, x - 1, 0, y - 1)
    dataImporter.SetDataExtentToWholeExtent()
    dataImporter.SetDataSpacing(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) 


    # volumeMapper
    volumeMapper = vtk.vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper()
    volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(dataImporter.GetOutputPort())
    # volumeMapper.SetBlendModeToComposite()

    # volumeColor
    volumeColor = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
    volumeColor.AddRGBPoint(0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    volumeColor.AddRGBPoint(50, 1, 1, 1)
    # volumeGradientOpacity
    volumeGradientOpacity = vtk.vtkPiecewiseFunction()
    volumeGradientOpacity.AddPoint(10, 0)
    volumeGradientOpacity.AddPoint(255, 1)
    # vtk Lookup Table
    lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
    lut.SetTableRange(1, 255)
    lut.SetHueRange(0.6, 0)  # Adjust the colors
    lut.Build()


    # volumeProperty (volumeScalarOpacity + volumeColor)
    volumeProperty = vtk.vtkVolumeProperty()
    volumeProperty.SetColor(volumeColor)
    volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(volumeGradientOpacity)
    volumeProperty.SetInterpolationTypeToLinear()
    # volumeProperty.ShadeOn()
    volumeProperty.SetAmbient(0.9)
    volumeProperty.SetDiffuse(0.9)
    volumeProperty.SetSpecular(0.9)

    # volume (volumeMapper + volumeProperty)
    volume = vtk.vtkVolume()
    volume.SetMapper(volumeMapper)
    volume.SetProperty(volumeProperty)

    # Renderer (add volume in) (two method?)
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderer.AddViewProp(volume)
    # renderer.AddVolume(volume)
    renderer.SetBackground(0, 0, 0)  # background color

    # set camera (volume / renderer)
    camera = renderer.GetActiveCamera()
    c = volume.GetCenter()
    camera.SetFocalPoint(c[0], c[1], c[2])
    camera.SetPosition(c[0] + 400, c[1], c[2])
    camera.SetViewUp(0, 0, -1)

    # RenderWindow
    renderWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renderWin.SetSize(640, 480)
    renderWin.AddRenderer(renderer)

    # RenderWindowInteractor
    interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderWin)

    # show the data in plot
    interactor.Initialize()
    renderWin.Render()
    interactor.Start()
```

using the numpy_support in vtk modules still get the bad result

Comment: Volume rendering in pure VTK is incredibly difficult and low level. I highly recommend you try using PyVista (which is a direct wrapping of VTK) or ParaView they will make volume rendering much simpler. What you likey want to do here would be 500+ lines of code with VTK and like 10-20 in PyVista